# writing LINQ query to pivot the result

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have developed a `LINQ` query. Now my requirement is to create pivot query from it. I am new to `LINQ`, I do not know how to proceed further. Please see the attached the attached result image.

```
public JsonResult SchoolNikashaRpt()
        {
            try
            {
                var temp = (from n in db.Nikashas
                           join s in db.Schools on n.SchoolId equals s.SchoolId
                           join k in db.Programs on n.ProgramId equals k.ProgramId
                           orderby n.SchoolId
                           select new RptSchoolsNikashaViewModel
                           {
                                SCHOOL_NAME = s.SCHOOL_NAME
                               ,PROGRAM_NAME = k.PROGRAM_NAME
                               ,MAPPED_AMOUNT = n.MAPPED_AMOUNT
                           }).ToList();

                return Json(temp, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Involved model classes are as follows::

```
public class NikashaModels
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int NIKASHAId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public decimal MAPPED_AMOUNT { get; set; }       
        
        [ForeignKey("ProgramId")]
        public ProgramModels Program { get; set; } 
        public int ProgramId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("SchoolId")]
        public SchoolModels School { get; set; }
        public int SchoolId { get; set; }
    }
    
public class SchoolModels 
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int SchoolId { get; set; }        
        public string SCHOOL_NAME { get; set; }        
    }
    
 public class ProgramModels
    {
        [Key]
        public int ProgramId { get; set; }
        public string PROGRAM_NAME { get; set; }                 
    }
```

[image]

Comment: It is not possible with any currently available LINQ providers, especially EF Core. So just write old good SQL.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I found this link https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/810267/Pivot-Grid-in-ASP-NET-MVC but do not know how to implement it. Please can you see it once. Thank You!!!

Comment: If you have a budget, better to look at something like that https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/PivotGrid/WebAPIService/Mvc/Light/
This grid can connect to OData endpoint.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv No, I have to look for free solutions.

Answer (score 0):

So you have `Nikashas`, `Schools` and `Programs`. There is a one-to-many relation: Every `Nikasha` has exactly one `School`, and exactly one `Program`, namely the School and Program that the foreign key refers to. In the other direction: Every School has zero or more Nikashas, every Program has zero or more Nikashas.

You want for every Nikasha, some properties, and some information of its School and its Program. For this you can use one of the overloads of [Enumerable.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join), if more than two tables are involved it is easier to do this using [Enumerab.Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select)

You didn't mention it, but because I see the word `db`, it seems to me that you are fetching the data from a DbContext, so your Enumerables are `IQueryable<...>`. This doesn't influence the answer very much:

```
IQueryable<Nikasha> nikashas = db.Nikashas
     // only if you don't want all Nikashas:
     .Where(nikasha => ...);
IQueryable<School> schools = ...
IQueryable<Program> programs = ...

var result = nikashas.Select(nikasha => new RptSchoolsNikashaViewModel
{
    // Get the name of the one and only School of this nikasha
    SchoolName = schools
        // Keep only the School that the foreign key refers to:
        .Where(school => school.Id == nikasha.SchoolId)

        // Select the name of the School
        .Select(school => school.SchoolName)

        // and take the first element
        .FirstOrDefault(),

    // Do something similar with the program name:
    ProgramName = programs.Where(program => program.Id == nikasha.ProgramId)
        .Select(program => program.ProgramName)
        .FirstOrDefault(),

    MappedAmount = nikasha.MappedAmount,
});
```

In words: from every Nikasha, make one new RptSchoolsNikashaViewModel. For this RptSchoolsNikashaViewModel use the MappedAmount of the Nikasha. To get the SchoolName, take all Schools that have a primary key value equal to the foreign key in the Nikasha. From the remaining schools (probably only one), take the name of the School. Finally take the first item from the remaining school names. Do something similar for ProgramNames.